# Python: I don't know why this keeps giving me KeyError: 5

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here is the code in question: I've isolated the problem line to "e5y.append(er[item+1])".
My problem is that I am unable to see how this line if faulty or why it prompts a key error:5

```
def Age_Analysis(x,y,z):
    a1y=[]
    b2y=[]
    c3y=[]
    d4y=[]
    e5y=[]
    xx=[]
    List=[]
    if y >= 1:
        for item in range(y):
            if z == 'range':
                ar = grp1[x].value_counts()
                br = grp2[x].value_counts()
                cr = grp3[x].value_counts()
                dr = grp4[x].value_counts()
                er = grp5[x].value_counts()
                
                a1y.append(ar[item+1])
                b2y.append(br[item+1])
                c3y.append(cr[item+1])
                d4y.append(dr[item+1])
                e5y.append(er[item+1])
                
                xx.append(x+"_"+str(item+1))
Age_Analysis('Q22',7,'range')
```

Edit: I figured it out!

Comment: `er` is a dictionary that doesn't contain the key `5`. that's it.

Comment: Yup, I understand now, thanks!

Comment: Actually, it brings up another issue. If the dictionary doesn't contain the key 5, how do I tell python to interpret a 5 key as having the value 0?

Comment: @JeffreyLin what you're looking for is a `defaultdict`.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> mydict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
>>> mydict[5]
```

Comment: just use `get`. `er.get(item + 1, 0)`